# Honda accord 07 leak in trunk. Water coming from seam underneath rear windshield

Tags: honda, accord, windshield, water-leak, trunk

Water drips down into the trunk of my Honda accord 2007.
[image: dripping water]

I think that the leak is coming from under the rear windshield[image]

as the whole seam was rusted and puckered and I was only able to redo the seam sealer up until under the window.
what is a cheap quick fix without removing my rear windshield cosmetics are not important to me.

Answer (score 2):

There are gaps in the window seal to the left and right of the area you marked in blue. I would use silicon chaulk, which remains flexible after it dries, to fill these gaps and see if that mitigates water getting into your trunk. If water is still getting into your trunk, the trunk lid seal at the bottom of the circle you marked in blue is not holding its shape and may be another cause of why water is getting into your trunk. Try pulling it up a bit to provide a better seal or replace it with a new trunk seal/gasket.

Comment: If I understand how the car gutter system works. Water normally flows under the window seal from the roof of the car. I imagine that I would have to seal 6 inches past the high part of the roof.

Comment: Do you mean rtv silicon?

Comment: You should fill any gaps that exist between the window and the exterior window trim/seal. You can use RTV silicone or a tube of 100% silicone chaulk from your local big box home improvement store. Either would work.